# Borg backup remotely gives error

Tags: linux, synology

Trying to use borg to backup Machine 1 to a remote Machine 2(which is synology), gives the error

```
Remote: sh: borg: command not found
Connection closed by remote host. Is borg working on the server?
```

All permissions and firewall have been tested. Machine1 can ssh to Machine2 but when trying to do `borg init --encryption=repokey borgdemo@Machine2:./demo` from Machine1, it is giving the above error. Trying to use borg on Machine2 works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found the answer here.
https://pod.disroot.org/posts/e18176ef-415c-e091-c340-9b5239891533

So, doing `which borg` on Machine1 was giving me `/usr/bin/borg` and on Machine2 the output was `/usr/local/bin/borg`. 
All it takes is to create a symlink on Machine2 so it will look like this

```
borg -> /usr/local/bin/borg
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, **you cannot create such a symlink** on the remote server (not enough rights on machine 2)

so, the quickest way to deal with different paths is to use the *--remote-path* argument on the client side:

```
/usr/bin/borg init --remote-path /usr/local/bin/borg borgdemo@Machine2:./demo
```

...but the best solution is to **force an absolute path on the server side** on the ssh config

```
$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
command="/usr/local/bin/borg serve" ssh-ed25519 AAAAC...xyz
```

with this setting, every borg connection from the client through the ssh tunnel will be handled on the server side calling the right binary